# Instagram Authentication

Tags: java, oauth, instagram, instagram-api

my problem is that I don't know how to get verifier code from the redirected URL. The code is being echoed in the body.

```
  HttpURLConnection igConnection = (HttpURLConnection) instagramURL.openConnection();
  igConnection.setDoInput(true);
  igConnection.setDoOutput(false);

  if (igConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
    InputStream is = igConnection.getInputStream();

    String response = "";

    if (is != null){
      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

      StringBuffer input = new StringBuffer();
      String line;
      while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        input.append(line);
      }
      in.close();

      System.out.println(input.toString());
    }
  }
```

What I do get is beginning like `<html>`...

I just wanted to refresh the accessToken in case it expires in the future (checking).

My authorization link is correct according to this [pattern](https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=code)